# How to show AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting object programmatically?

Tags: c#, controls, rdp

I'm creating a RDP multitab Forms application. Once the application starts, it attempts to open a new tab for each connection like this:

```cs
foreach (RDPData rdp in root.Value)
{
    AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting rdpClient = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
    rdpClient.CreateControl();
    rdpClient.Server = rdp.Server;
    rdpClient.UserName = rdp.User;
    rdpClient.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdpClient.GetOcx();
    secured.ClearTextPassword = rdp.Password;
    rdpClient.Connect();
    TabPage tab = new TabPage(rdp.Alias);
    tab.Controls.Add(rdpClient);
    rdpClient.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
}
```

No error message is thrown. I see that the tab is correctly created but it doesn't show any content. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the view is not getting refresh after the FILL.  Move the Fill before the Add.

Comment: Still the same. No content is shown.

Comment: Is the query returning any data?

Comment: M$ application RDCMan use .NET and MDI interface to host RDP COM component:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44989

Maybe you can find in the IL nessesary code. For example RdcMan.RdpClient class use RdpClient(MainForm form) and RdpClient.AllocClient(Server, MainForm) and new RdpClient(MainForm).Initialize(MainForm) to host window in MDI application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I started a new Visual Studio project, added the necessary references and tested with a single `AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting` object. Then I looked into the automatically generated code in the `InitializeComponent`. I noticed the following lines of code in the method:

```cs
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // ...
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MyTestForm));
    // ...
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.rdp)).BeginInit();
    // ...
    // 
    // rdp
    // 
    this.rdp.Enabled = true;
    this.rdp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
    this.rdp.Name = "rdp";
    this.rdp.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("rdp.OcxState")));
    this.rdp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(804, 602);
    this.rdp.TabIndex = 0;
    // ...
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.rdp)).EndInit();
    // ...
}
```

So, this is what I did foreach RDP in the loop of my question:

```cs
foreach (RDPData rdp in root.Value)
{
    AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting rdpClient = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(rdpClient)).BeginInit();
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(RDPMultiTabForm));
    rdpClient.Enabled = true;
    rdpClient.Name = rdp.Alias;
    rdpClient.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("rdpClient.OcxState")));
    TabPage tab = new TabPage(rdp.Alias);
    rdpClient.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tab.Controls.Add(rdpClient);
    tab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(rdpClient)).EndInit();
    rdpClient.Server = rdp.Server;
    rdpClient.UserName = rdp.User;
    rdpClient.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdpClient.GetOcx();
    secured.ClearTextPassword = rdp.Password;
    rdpClient.Connect();
}
```